# Where to find in IBM Websphere 7.0 admin console to configure http_access.log to show response time

Tags: websphere

We are using **IBM Websphere 7.0 Server**. I need to configure to see response time in the `http_access.log`. I navigated through most of the admin console options, but I am not sure where to find it.

Comment: please have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/13551298/592355 ...and even @ http://serverfault.com/a/173573/102741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM68250 added the custom log formats to WAS 7.0.0.25 and later:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM68250

> To enable this new functionality please add the "accessLogFormat"
>   custom property to the HTTP Channel, the panel on the administrative
>   console can be found here:
>           Application Servers > {Server Name} > Web Container Transport Chains > {Chain Name} > {HTTP Channel Name} > Custom Properties
>
> Also, please ensure the "Use chain-specific logging" option is enabled on the HTTP Channel where the previously mentioned property is
>   enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer covener.  What value should "accessLogFormat" have?.   In addition to that, In "Use Chain-specific logging->Access log file path" field should hold?