# My REST API calls to Salesforce work through RunScope (an API debugging site) but not directly to Salesforce

Tags: rest, ssl, salesforce, websphere

So right now I'm trying to make a bunch of REST API calls to Salesforce from my WebSphere server, but every time I make a request, I get a "500 Server Error" error message in my logs. I then tried to run my API calls through RunScope to try and debug what was going wrong. As soon as I sent my API calls through RunScope to Salesforce, the 500 Error went away and everything worked. I instantly thought it was some kind of SSL Protocol issue since Salesforce apparently doesn't support SSL3.0. So I checked my WebSphere configuration and noticed that it supports both SSL and TLS protocols (I'm not 100% sure which protocol it's using though, if anyone knows of a way to test that, that would be helpful). Now I'm pretty stumped. I know it's not a certificate issue because i installed the needed certificates on my WebSphere server. Anyone else have any ideas why the API calls work through RunScope to Salesforce but not directly to Salesforce? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the response payload that goes with the 500 response?

Comment: @superfell all that I've ever been able to get returned back to me through my server is "500 Server Error". I have been unable to get a more detailed response message..

Comment: You won't get anywhere without being able to see what the body is that goes with the 500 status code.

Comment: You might be able to get some information by Tracing the HTTP requests. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13551298/6216002).

Comment: @superfell so i was finally able to access the body of the error (i think) and it says to contact the salesforce support team with the error ID i was given, so I think we're good here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My issue was that my WebSphere server was running TLS1.0 which isn't supported anymore by Salesforce. If you're running into the same issues as me, make sure your server is running TLS 1.1 or higher.